# Skipping extra line while inserting variable in perl

Tags: perl, subroutine

I have this PERL subroutine

```
sub request
{
#INPUTS
....
....
my $users_info = @_[5] ;
my $req_exp = <<DOC;
#SN# Step $number
#DN# AUTHENT $type_authent + PFS SERVICE
#ED# $reponse
GET /$jonction/testussowt/printenv HTTP/1.1
Host : $HOST
$users_info
---
DOC
return $req_exp ;
}
```

if i call it like this

```
my $test = &request(other_arguments..,'user1');
print $test ;
```

I get the correct output ( i am showing only the last two lines that matter)

```
user1
---
```

But if i call it like this

```
my $var = &other_sub_that_returns_a_string;
my $test = &request(other_arguments..,$var);
print $test;
```

I got this extra empty line in my output

```
user1

---
```

Comment: Are you sure that `other_sub_that_returns_a_string` removes any newline characters at the end of the string? If, in the case you use that sub, you apply `chomp $var;`, do you get the same behaviour?

Comment: By adding `chomp $var;` the  problem is fixed but what is the problem ?`other_sub_that_returns_a_string` only returns a value and there is no `\n` or anything like this !

Comment: That can't be correct. `chomp` **only** removes newline characters at the end of a string, so the function has to be adding one or keeping one.

Comment: Check http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Without the full code, it's hard to say exactly what's happening here.

Best guess is that your subroutine is returning with a line break at the end, or pulling the line break from somewhere else.

To fix that:

```
my $var = &other_sub_that_returns_a_string;
chomp($var);
my $test = &request(other_arguments..,$var);
print $test;
```

If you post your code, I can definitely take a look and try to help you figure out where the line break is coming from.